# PayPal Express - remove "PayPal Credit" option?

Tags: user-interface, paypal, express-checkout

I'm implementing PayPal express with checkout.js ([per docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-integration/)) and there doesn't seem to be any option to remove the (IMHO) overly aggressive prompt to apply for PayPay Credit.

For small purchases - like with my use case (average purchase amount = $3) this seems silly - I don't think applying for credit for a $3 purchase is realistic. What's more - this block is a dominant part of the UI element that I think will distract the end user from completing check out.

Anyone have guidance/workaround / similar frustrations?

When I test my Production tokens and Production user - I don't see the "PayPal Credit" prompt - it's the streamlined flow I would prefer! I believe this probably has to do with the settings on the Buyer account, but I'm just not sure and want to make sure I understand.

[image: illustration]

Comment: edit: when I test my Production tokens and Production user - I don't see the "PayPal Credit" prompt - it's the streamlined flow I would prefer! I believe this probably has to do with the settings on the Buyer account, but I'm just not sure and want to make sure I understand...

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Credit option is enabled for all sandbox accounts by default. This is the reason for showing the PayPal Credit option at checkout. If you want to remove this option from the checkout page, please file [PayPal MTS ticket](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/) with your sandbox merchant PayPal account email address.

Then PayPal MTS engineers will disable the option for you.